# CSS for an image sitting inside a div within a lightbox (Many layers)

Tags: html, css, lightbox

I am having some issues getting my head around the dimensions of an image sitting within a div that is inside a lightbox. So to break it down:

1 light box
2 columns in the lightbox named lhc and rhc
The image sits in lhc but I no matter if I use % or px its distorts the thumb.

The image needs to not distort regardless of original size but needs to scale down and sit dead centre of the lhc div.

See code and where am I going wrong:

```
.imagebox_container {
    height: 600px;
    width: 800px;
}
.fancybox-prev {
    width: 20%;
}
.fancybox-next {
    width: 20%;
    right: 400px;
}
.lhc {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    background-color: #000;
}
.rhc {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.fancyimg{
        height: 50%; width: 50%; display:block;
    margin:auto; margin-top: 25%;}
```

Here is the html/php:

```
    <div class="imagebox_container">
  <div class="lhc"><img class="fancyimg" src="uploads/folio/<?php echo $imgdata['filename']; ?>" /></div>
  <div class="rhc">
    <div id="imagedetails">
      <div id="imagedetails_useravatar"></div>
      <div id="imagedetails_username"></div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div id="likeboard"></div>
    <div id="commentboard">
      <?php /* Load comments */ ?>
      <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_comments)){ ?>
      <div class="commentbox"><span class=""><span class="comment"><?php echo $row['comment']; ?></span></span></div>
      <hr />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issues, see my code. Works perfectly ok now.

```
.imagebox_container { height: 600px; width: 1000px; }
.fancybox-prev { width: 20%; }
.fancybox-next { width: 20%; right: 400px; }

.lhc { width: 700px;
       height: 100%;
       position: relative;
       float: left;
       display: block;
       background-image: url('/graphics/ps_neutral.png');
       clear: both;
       text-align: center; }     

.rhc { width: 300px;
       height: 100%;
       background-color: #FFF;
       height: auto;
       position: relative;  
       float: right;
       overflow-y: scroll; }

.fancyimg { max-height: 80%;
            max-width: 80%; 
            display:block;
            position:absolute;
            margin-top: 10%;
            margin-left: 70px;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
            box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was playing around with max-heights/widths but am a little closer...

```
.fancyimg{
        max-height: 50%; max-width: 50%; display:block;
    margin:auto; margin-top: 25%;}
```